# Angular2 RC5: get json data from web service not working

Tags: json, angular, dataservice

I am trying to load data from data service but ID appears as type error

```
selectedModule(item: any) {
  this.module = item;
    console.log(this.module);
    this.dataService.getAny('/modules/get-by-module', "Id", '1')
        .then((module: IModuleBySector) => {
            const cust = JSON.stringify(module);
            this.moduleSelected = module;
            console.log(this.moduleSelected);
    });
 }
```

Comment: What "ID"? How does the data service look like?

Comment: Please add the exact error message to your question.

Comment: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: ID which is '1'

Comment: This question doesn't provide enough information to diagnose the problem. The problem is obviously not in the code you posted because this code doesn't access `id`.

Comment: does your data service expect a number, and not a string?

Comment: it expect a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to send **ID** to the server side code and want to get data whose **ID=1**. You should try this,

```
selectedModule(item: any) {
  this.module = item;
    console.log(this.module);
    this.dataService.getAny('/modules/get-by-module?Id=1')
        .then((module: IModuleBySector) => {
            const cust = JSON.stringify(module);
            this.moduleSelected = module;
            console.log(this.moduleSelected);
    });
 }
```

Comment: ERROR message: supplied parameters don't match any signatures of call target

Comment: Can you show how getAny method looks like? And what your server side code expects?